# deprecation error using GnuPG in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnupg, pgp

I am trying to decrypt a pgp file using the python library called 'python-gnupg', I tried to decrypt the file using python 3.7 and all went well, however when I try to switch to python 3.8 the function fails stating the following.

```
'gpg: WARNING: "--secret-keyring" is an obsolete option - it has no effect\ngpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.\n[GNUPG:] NODATA 1\n[GNUPG:] NODATA 2\n[GNUPG:] FAILURE decrypt 4294967295\ngpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error\n'
```

This is part of the sample code that I use, that's not all code but is part of the function of decryption.

```
import gnupg

gpg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/gpg'
gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary=gpg_binary)
status = gpg.decrypt_file("/user/folder/file.pgp",
                        passphrase=PASS,
                        output="/user/folder/file.csv")
```

Comment: Speaking as a former contributor to python-gnupg -- that library is an utter mess. Not its maintainers' fault, but the fault of gnupg for creating such a gnarly and constantly-changing interface; the devolution of something trying to follow it into spaghetti code is almost unavoidable. Personally, I rewrote my tools that formerly used that library in Go, using [`x/crypto/openpgp`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp)

Comment: BTW, are you _very_ sure it's the Python version changing that made the difference? The message you posted implied that the gnupg version changed at the same time. Because python-gnupg runs the native/C gnupg executable (and because, as I mentioned, upstream gnupg is wildly irresponsible about backwards API compatibility), it's _very_ sensitive to that executable's versioning.

Comment: That said, do double check that the error message isn't speaking truth when it says that `/user/folder/file.gpg` doesn't contain valid GPG packet data. If you're writing content to that file from elsewhere in your Python program, f/e, be sure you're actually flushing it to disk / closing the file in Python before you open it with gnupg.